# Draw on leaflet/svg polygon

Tags: html, canvas, svg, leaflet, gradient

I'm currently implementing a map in leaflet, which contains some 100 or so polygons. My problem is that I will need to draw on the polygons (or replace them) with an algorithm that determines the color of each point in the Polygon; currently an isolated Inverse Distance Weighting algorithm (IDW) to produce isolated heatmaps within the polygons.

For illustration, think of drawing something like:

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1376/screenshots/81962/shot_1290433321.png

-- within the polygon.

Now, how would you do it?

Note that one Polygon, once added to leaflet, produces an svg like the following one:

```
<g>

  <path class="leaflet-interactive" 
    stroke="#3388ff" 
    stroke-opacity="1" 
    stroke-width="3" 
    stroke-linecap="round" 
    stroke-linejoin="round" 
    fill="#3388ff" 
    fill-opacity="0.2" 
    fill-rule="evenodd" 
    d="M515 304L515 347L160 684L160 304z">
  </path>

  <path class="leaflet-interactive" 
    stroke="#3388ff" 
    stroke-opacity="1" 
    stroke-width="3" 
    stroke-linecap="round" 
    stroke-linejoin="round" 
    fill="#3388ff" 
    fill-opacity="0.2" 
    fill-rule="evenodd" 
    d="M515 304L515 347L160 684L160 304z">
</path>

</g>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best solution is to create an svg `<g>` element for the map. Place your svg polygon elements into the group. Then work your magic directly on these standard svg polygon elements.
To create this svg `<g>` use: L.svg().addTo(map);

RE: *i'm still completely lost on how to actually "draw" inside one of the paths*

Create an svg clipPath element with the polygon (or path) points. Then include the clip-path attribute on the image you want to clip

Comment: Thanks! However, i'm still completely lost on how to actually "draw" inside one of the paths (i/e replacing the fill of the polygons with complex patterns that does not go outside of the path)

Comment: Thanks again, this is what I ended up doing. :)